# SQL Query to_char BETWEEN returns wrong results along with correct ones

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

My query is as follows:

```
select * from session ses
inner join event evt
on ses.evt_id = ses.id
inner join application app
on app.id = ses.app_id
where app.id = 9999
and ses.usernumber = 69
and to_char(ses_date, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH24:MI:SS') between '22.10.2015 23:59:59' and '23.10.2015 23:59:59'
```

Now, the first results are indeed from **23.10.2015** but there are also few from **23.06.2014**.

**How is this possible?**

Comment: Character string comparison works that way. Switch to proper timestamp data type, or at least ANSI/ISO format '2015-10-22 23:59:59'.

Answer (score 4):

Why convert that date to a string in the first place? This is inefficient, and unsafe. Instead, you can filter the column directly against literal dates or timestamps.

I suspect you want:

```
ses_date >= date '2015-10-22' and ses_date < date '2015-10-24'
```

This brings dates whose day portion is 2015, October 22nd or 23rd.

Of course, you can also use literal timestamps if you want. If you wanted to replicate the logic of your original code:

```
ses_date >= timestamp '2015-10-22 23:59:59' and ses_date <= timestamp '2015-10-23 23:59:59'
```

---

If you are receiveing the date parameters as strings in the first place, then convert them to dates:

```
ses_date between to_date('22.10.2015T23:59:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy"T"hh24:mi:ss')
             and to_date('23.10.2015T23:59:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy"T"hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: I need to use Strings, because I parse the date from an URL to which a user types "&start=22.10.2015T23:59:59&end=23.10.2020T23:59:59"

Comment: @willberthos: then convert the strings to date. See my update.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, but as I am using JPQL, I can not use to_date function. I've yet to find the way to convert String to the right JPQL format, from which I made a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64857100/sql-jpql-parse-string-to-date-that-is-accepted-in-jpql

Comment: @willberthos: why not just: `ses_date between to_date(?1, 'dd.mm.yyyy"T"hh24:mi:ss') and to_date(?2, 'dd.mm.yyyy"T"hh24:mi:ss')`

Comment: because JPQL does not have "to_date" function

Answer (score 4):

> How is this possible?

You are using `TO_CHAR` on a date data type to convert it to a string data type and then the filter is:

```
{string value} BETWEEN {string value} AND {string value}
```

So the SQL parser performs an alpha-numeric comparison of the values and the lower bound starts `22` and `23.06.2014` is greater as the first characters of the string are the same and then the second character is compared and `2` < `3` so `'22.10.2015 23:59:59'` < `'23.06.2014'` when compared as a string. Similarly, the upper bound starts with `23.1` and the first 3 characters are the same and then `0` < `1` for the 4th character so `'23.06.2014'` < `'23.10.2015 23:59:59'` (again, when compared as a string). So the filter returns true as the string value is between the upper and lower bounds.

How to solve this:

Don't compare the values as strings; compare them as dates.

```sql
AND ses_date BETWEEN DATE '2015-10-22' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND
             AND     DATE '2015-10-23' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND
```

or

```sql
AND ses_date BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2015-10-22 23:59:59'
             AND     TIMESTAMP '2015-10-23 23:59:59'
```

or

```sql
AND ses_date BETWEEN TO_DATE( '22.10.2015 23:59:59', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )
             AND     TO_DATE( '23.10.2015 23:59:59', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )
```

*(Note: these will return values from including `2015-10-22 23:59:59`.)*

If you only want values that are at any time on `2015-10-23` then:

```sql
AND ses_date >= DATE '2015-10-23'
AND ses_date <  DATE '2015-10-24'
```

Answer (score 1):

You expect your values to be evaluated as dates, where the year component is the most important, which can be found at the end of your date description. However, due to the fact that you convert your dates to strings, they are evaluated alphabetically, which means that in the comparison the first difference (from left to right) decides the outcome. Alphabetically

**22.10.2015 23:59:59 < 23.06.2014 < 23.10.2015 23:59:59**

is true.

## Proof

All three strings start with a '2'. The first continues with another '2', while the second continues with a '3'. So the first is smaller than the second. The third continues with a '3', just like the second. Both the second and the third continues with a '.'. And now comes the difference: the first continues with '0' and the third continues with a '1'. Even though these strings represent dates for you and the year component of the third is smaller than the second's, as strings the second is smaller than the third.

## How to solve this?

Several approaches can be used.

### Convert your input that you filter by to date

Basically, if you do not convert your dates to string, but your inputs `to_date`, as @GMB described, then it should work properly.

### Hungarian date notation

Even though the first approach should work out of the box and is a perfectly feasible solution, if, for some reason that's not an option (for example the dates in the URL might be malformed due to user searches), then you might want to use the format of yyyy.mm.dd in your URL and use that format in your `to_char` conversions. The idea behind this is that if year component comes first, followed by the month and then the date component, then the comparison between two values will have similar results, independently of whether you compare the values as dates or as strings.